# How to group multiple record using aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to group on the basis of the element key that can be similar in many records.
Business_portfolio_attributes details

```
[{
"_id" : ObjectId("613f2428d62bbe20db999133"),
"status" : 1,
"element" : "Current Assets",
"instituteBenchMarkId" : ObjectId("613b11006845993d61346bf9"),
"attributeValue" : 352907.04,
"startDate" : ISODate("2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"reportId" : ObjectId("613f2427d62bbe20db999130"),
"businessId" : ObjectId("61370a5ac3941822005f91de"),
"category" : "BS",
"__v" : 0,
"createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-13T10:12:56.334Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-13T10:12:56.334Z")
```

}]

The query I have used is mentioned below. Any alternative for this query?

```
db.getCollection('business_portfolio_attributes').aggregate([
{$match: { category: "BS"}},
{$group: { _id: "$instituteBenchMarkId", elements:{ $push: {
    "element": "$element",
    "startDate": "$startDate"
    } }} }
```

])

Comment: can you add expected output structure? i don't seem to understand what you want.

Comment: why you need alternative? you are not getting the results you need? your query looks ok